# Camel onException - Route with same exception class but different actions

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel

Within a single camel route I have two url calls, making calls to two different applications.

```
to("http://datasource1/data)
//some process
to("http://datasource2/data)
//some process
```

Both are capable of throwing `UnKnowHostException`. 
So, if the URL1 throws the exception i have to handled and set the exchange body as "Datasource 1 not available" and if URL2 throws the same exception , I want to show a different message.

How to handle this using **onException**

Comment: Maybe you can use 2 try/catch blocks in your route to handle the exceptions separately instead of using onException blocks? See http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onWhen`. Set some header (in my example "httpDatasource") before each request, and after use different handlers.

```
    onException(UnKnowHostException.class).onWhen(header("httpDatasource").isEqualTo("1")).to("...");
    onException(UnKnowHostException.class).onWhen(header("httpDatasource").isEqualTo("2")).to("...");

    .....
    setHeader("httpDatasource").constant("1")
    to("http://datasource1/data)
    //some process
    setHeader("httpDatasource").constant("2")
    to("http://datasource2/data)
    //some process
```

Comment: You can use  any other simple expression in `onWhen`. Maybe based on parsing a content of  exception  message,  or  use `CamelHttpUri` header to select desired  handler.

Comment: I dont want a work around. am expecting a clean solution or a convincible statement saying "Its impossible to do with onException

Answer (score 1):

I would use the camel `try catch` blocks (as suggested by @soilworker).

```
.doTry()
    .to("http://datasource1/data")
.doCatch(UnknownHostException.class)
    // Add message 1 here
.end()
//process
.doTry()
    .to("http://datasource2/data")
.doCatch(UnknownHostException.class)
    // Add message 2 here
.end()
// process
```

It's more verbose, but it's easy to understand and clearly associates the message with the exception.  And in the event you wish to make the `to` calls asynchronous, you can.

You can use a route specific `onException` but you would need to split your route into multiple routes:

```
from("somewhere")
    .to("direct:datasource1")
    //process
    .to("direct:datasource2")
    //process

from("direct:datasource1")
    .onException(UnknownHostException.class)
        // add message 1 here
    .end()
    .to("http://datasource/data")

from("direct:datasource2")
    .onException(UnknownHostException.class)
        // add message 2 here
    .end()
    .to("http://datasource2/data")
```

I don't believe there's a way of using `onException` with the one route but applied to different `to` calls (other than using @Alexeys or @Ewouts suggestion).  Would love to hear about it if there is.